# Can't use NSTextField delegate in NSDocument

Tags: core-data, delegates, nstextfield, nsdocument

I have a document-based project with a view-based tableView bound to a coreData Entity.
Now I'd like to use the delegate controlTextDidChange: with a static text inside a tableViewColumn.

What I'v done is adding NSTextFieldDelegate to my xxxxDocument.h (my File's owner):

```
@interface BLDocument : NSPersistentDocument <NSTableViewDelegate,NSTextFieldDelegate>
```

and implementing in xxxxDocument.m -controlTextDidChange to log something:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj{
NSLog(@"edited");
}
```

then in the .xib I connected the StaticText delegate to the file's owner, but nothing works still.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don't show some code.

Comment: I thought it was clear enough. I add some now.

Comment: Try implement in your viewWillAppear method " nameOfYourTextField.delegate = self; "